# How would you prevent a user from inputting a duplicate value in a linked list?

Tags: linked-list

I've been trying to figure out how to prevent a user from entering a duplicate value and honestly I am struggling so much for an answer that's probably really simple once I see it, but I can't. The function is below along with the struct node. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

````
struct node {
  int data = -1;
  node * current;
  node * next;
};
node * start = NULL;


```
void addNode(struct node & n) {
  if (n.data == -1) {
    cout << "List not created yet." << endl;
  } else {
    node * temp;
    node * temp2;
    temp = new node;

    cout << "What number would you like to enter:" << endl;
    cin >> temp -> data;
    cout << endl;
    int value;
    value = temp -> data;

    temp = start;
    while (temp != NULL) {

      if (temp -> data == value) {
        cout << "Duplicate Number!" << endl;
      } else {
        temp = temp -> next;
      }
      temp = temp -> next;
    }

    if (start == NULL) {
      start = temp;
    } else {

      temp2 = start;
      while (temp2 -> next != NULL) {
        temp2 = temp2 -> next;
      }
      temp2 -> next = temp;

    }

  }

}
````

Comment: You’d have to traverse the list to check but performance is going to get bad fast.

Comment: A linked list is the wrong data structure for this. You probably ought to be using a map.

Comment: Sadly, this is for an assignment and they wanted me to use a linked list

Comment: OK.  Then loop over the list every time to see if it already contains what the user inputs.  You could add in a set to check for dupes instead of looping over if that doesn't violate the parameters of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some remarks on your code:

- Don't make `start` a global variable. Instead make it local to `main` and pass it as argument to the `addNode` function
- Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`
- Don't ask for the user's input inside the `addNode` function. By the principle of *separation of concern*, keep the I/O aspects outside that function.
- Instead pass the value as argument to `addNode`
- You should treat a node differently when it has the value -1. An empty list is not a list with one node that has the value -1. An empty list is a null pointer.
- Even if a list is empty, it should be possible to add the first node with this function
- Use more descriptive variable names. `n` for a `node` instance is not very clear. Also `temp` and `temp2` are not very clear. One of the two is the newly created node, so it could be named `newNode`.
- After you have created the new node, and assigned its reference to `temp`, you assign a new value to `temp` with `temp = start`, and so you've lost (and leaked) the newly created node.
- In your loop, you'll execute `temp = temp->next` twice when the value does not match. This should of course only be done once per iteration.
- Even when your code finds a duplicate and outputs a message, it still continues the process. Instead you should stop the process, and *not* create the node (or if you already did: dispose it with `delete`).
- It is a pity that you need to traverse the list again from the start to find the last node and append the new node there. You should be able to do that in the first loop where you look for the duplicate.

Here is a correction:

```cpp
bool addNode(node* &start, int value) {
    node * current = start;
    if (start != nullptr) {
        while (current->data != value && current->next != nullptr) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        if (current->data == value) {
            return false; // duplicate!
        }
    }
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = value;
    if (start != nullptr) {
        current->next = newNode;
    } else {
        start = newNode;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that this function returns a boolean: if `true` then the node was inserted. The other case means there was a duplicate.

Your main function could look like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    // define start as local variable
    node * start = nullptr; // Use nullptr instead of NULL
    while (true) {
        int value;
        // Don't do I/O together with list-logic
        cout << "What number would you like to enter:" << endl;
        cin >> value;
        cout << endl;
        if (value == -1) break;
        if (!addNode(start, value)) {
            cout << "Duplicate Number!" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```